# Casting in Java(interface and class)

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

if:

```
interface I{}

class A implements I{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends B{}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();

Why a = (B)(I)b; is correct
but b = (B)(I)a; is false?
```

I find casting to be very confusing, what is the best way to understand if I can down cast or up cast an object?

Comment: Why are you casting to `I` at all? If you removed all mention of `I`, and just had `a = (B) b;` and `b = (B) a;` would that be clear to you?

Comment: @JonSkeet this is a java exam question i am also very confused why they casting an Interface "I"

Comment: Both of those casts are correct (as in they both compile and won't fail at runtime).  What specifically are you seeing that makes them not compile in Java 7+?

Comment: @Makoto the answer says the second one will fail at run time but i have no idea why.

Comment: This is something that's easily verifiable; the cast doesn't fail at runtime either.

Comment: @taimeili123 Please see my updated answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your class hierarchy looks like this:

[image: C -> B -> A -> I]

Object `x` can be casted to class `Y`, if runtime type of `x` is subclass of `Y`. Or, in other words, if there is a path from runtime type of `x` to `Y`. By "runtime type" i mean the type of object (the one used when constructing object) as opposed to type of variable (the one from variable declaration).

This is valid:

```
b = new B();
(B)(I)b;
```

Object stored in `b` has type `B`. It's  casted to `I` and then back to `B`. `B` is a subclass of both of them. Cast to `I` doesn't actually do anything and is meant only to confuse you.

However, neither of those is valid:

```
a = new A();
(B)(I)a;
(B)a;
```

They will both fail with exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to B`. `a` has type `A` which is not a subclass of `B`. There is a relation between `A` and `B`, but it's in the opposite direction - `B` is a subclass of `A`.

For more detailed explanation see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

The only thing of relevance to answering the question in your coding sample is the following:

```
class B extends A{}
```

This means that B is a subclass of A. Subclasses can be cast to super class types, but super class cannot be cast to subclass types.

**Therefore, A cannot be cast to type B.**

Why? Think about the logic this way:

[image] is a type of `Programming_language`, but `Programming_language` is not a type of [image]